# Updated Version Wygwam for EE 1

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, ee1

I'm working on a site on EE 1, and need to update an old (2.0.4) version to a newer version, b/c theres some problem in IE. Is there anyway I can access EE 1 versions of Wygwam?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you contact [Pixel and Tonic](http://pixelandtonic.com/support) directly. They have a reputation for being responsive.

Comment: Ended up contacting them directly.